# Vuforia unexpected duplicate task on XCode for image target tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Vuforia unexpected duplicate task on XCode for image target tracking

Seems specific to that. Multi-target seems fine.

This requires that a brand new build folder get created each time. Very annoying bug.

Comment: What is the background? Is your problem related to the Vuforia-engine native sample? If yes what version of Vuforia and what xcode version?

Comment: vuforia for unity - added the tag